# How to call an API from an extended API in Sonar Plugin

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to call an sonar API `api/projects/index` inside an sonar plugin extended API.
It is not allow me to use `apache httpclient` when packaging the plugin so I used `Spring RestTemplate` to send the request but it not contains authenticated information.

Do you have some ideas?
Thank in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the plugin?

Comment: I am trying to get all projects, files, and SCM information of source files with the plugin. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: And these information will based on the permission of the current login user

Comment: is this a plugin that act from the server on live in the browser?
if you want to add a page for example, you can easily call the WS.
What is your version of SQ?

Comment: I am using sonarqube-6.1 and the plugin will be put into the `extensions\plugins` folder. In the extended webservice, I used `wsClient.projects()` but it only has create and delete methods and couldn't get all projects
`WsClient wsClient = WsClientFactories.getLocal().newClient(request.localConnector());`

Comment: are you trying to create a new page? if yes, then I would advise to wait for SQ 6.3 to have a new way to add pages